# "the rpc server is unavailable" when trying to do some process on local html file with autohotkey

Tags: automation, autohotkey, rpc

I have written the script that accesses the local HTML file and does some job.

```
^+A::
;Convert HTML TO ASCIIDOC
Send ^c
copied := Clipboard
sleep 30
local := "file:///C:/Users/emre/Desktop/Tools/Note%20Taking%20Tools/Asciidoc%20Tools/HtmlToAsciidoc-master/to-asciidoc.html"
sleep 100
(pwb5 := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")).Visible:=False

pwb5.navigate(local)
while pwb5.busy
    sleep 15

WinActivate,ahk_class IEFrame
ControlFocus,ahk_class IEFrame
Send, !n
Send, {Enter}


pwb5.document.getElementByID("source").value=copied
pwb5.document.getElementByID("conversion-button").Click()
Sleep 3000
Clipboard=pwb5.document.getElementByID("target").value
Return
```

When I run this script I get following error:

[image]

I have done some research and try following things but neither of these work.Any advice appreciated.

**Check 1**
I have checked DCOM Server Process Launcher, Remote Procedure Call (RPC) and RPC Endpoint Mapper from services.msc.All their status is Running and their startup is set to Automatic.

**Check 2**
I have also checked "Remote Assistance" from Firewall

**Check 3**
I have  also checked that "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" and "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)" are enabled

**Check 4**
I have  also checked "to switch the NIC from the default "NAT" to "Bridged Adapter" from Virtualbox settings.

Answer (score 1):

MAYBE this will help.  My issue sounds similar to yours. In my case, I have a vb.net program, part of which does something to the effect of the following:

```
Function LoadWebPage(i_IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, i_URL As String) As Boolean

    i_IE.navigate (i_URL)
    Debug.Print (i_IE.ReadyState)

End Function
```

The navigate method ran fine. But once it got to the point of returning the ReadyState property, I was getting the "RPC Server is unavailable" error. This was only happening on one of the three machines I was using. On the machine with the problem,  I ran through the steps (which I saw listed in many other sites as well) you mentioned in your question, with no improvement.  But then I came across a suggestion to adjust the "Internet Explorer Options-->Settings-->Security-->Enable Protected Mode".  Actually the site that helped me said to make sure that they are checked for all of the zones (i.e., Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites).  **Actually it was unchecking them  all** that resolved my issue.  I went back to one of the other two machines (one of those where the script was running without error), and indeed, they were unchecked on that machine (not sure yet about the 3rd machine).

[Fix for RPC Server Error when occuring with attempt at Internet Explorer Automation](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2rsr8b/automating_ie_getting_strange_behaviour_when/)

In case that post doesn't outlast this response, their stated reason for this issue:

> "The basic gist of it is when you cross a security domain (http to
>   https) the sandboxing system actually creates a new IE COM
>   object...The basic solution is to set all of the security modes in the
>   Security tab of Internet Settings to 'protected mode enabled'(sic) to
>   avoid losing COM objects."

Again, I think that may have been a typo on their part and that they meant that the boxes should be unchecked.

[image]